# POSIX Thread arguments

Tags: multithreading, posix

Can a pthread only take one argument?

So If I wanted to send in a number of arguments, would I send in a struct and open it inside the thread function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see the documentation on [pthread_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_create.html).  You can always bundle the needed information in a struct object as you suggest.